# Columns created by case statement do not group by

Tags: sql-server, case

Here is a T-SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    A.DateStamp,
    CASE WHEN A.T = 10 THEN A.counts END AS HT,  
    CASE WHEN A.T = 98 THEN A.counts END AS BP,
    CASE WHEN A.T = 94 THEN A.counts END AS MP,
    CASE WHEN A.T = 12 THEN A.counts END AS SP
FROM  
    A                        
WHERE 
    (A.date_time BETWEEN GETDATE() - 60 AND GETDATE() - 30)   -- say 
--GROUP BY A.DateStamp,A.T,A.counts
ORDER BY
    CONVERT(DATE, A.DateStamp) ASC
```

It works well. Previously I was using multiple copies of table A and all joined. over here results are correct but split in multiple rows like:

```
date       | BP | MP | SP | HT |
-----------+----+----+----+----+
22/10/2017   12   34   56   78
Looks Like   --   --   --   --
22/10/2017   12   --   --   --
22/10/2017   --   34   --   --
22/10/2017   --   --   56   --
22/10/2017   --   --   --   78
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use *conditional aggregation* for this and `GROUP BY` just the `DateStamp` field:

```
SELECT A.DateStamp,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.T=10 THEN A.counts ELSE 0 END) AS HT,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.T=98 THEN A.counts ELSE 0 END) AS BP,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.T=94 THEN A.counts ELSE 0 END) AS MP,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.T=12 THEN A.counts ELSE 0 END) AS SP
FROM  A                        
WHERE (A.date_time BETWEEN getdate()-60 AND getdate()-30) 
GROUP BY A.DateStamp
ORDER BY convert(date,A.DateStamp) ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess you need to group by date only

```
SELECT convert(date,A.DateStamp) AS Date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.T=10 THEN A.counts END) AS HT ,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.T=98 THEN A.counts END) AS BP,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.T=94 THEN A.counts END) AS MP,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.T=12 THEN A.counts END) AS SP
FROM  A                        
WHERE A.date_time BETWEEN getdate()-60 AND getdate()-30
GROUP BY convert(date,A.DateStamp) 
ORDER BY convert(date,A.DateStamp) ASC
```