# Columns created by case statement do not group by when use partition by

Tags: sql-server, pivot, case

I am doing reporting where I previously got into same problem but got it solved [here is the link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860280/columns-created-by-case-statement-do-not-group-by),

Over here I got the same problem with little change here I also require partition by

```
CASE WHEN MP.PT = 'OPD' THEN COUNT(MP.YN) OVER (PARTITION BY  MP.PT,mp.tti ORDER BY  mp.tti)   END AS OPD,
CASE WHEN MP.PT = 'IPD' THEN COUNT(MP.YN) OVER (PARTITION BY  MP.PT,mp.tti ORDER BY  mp.tti)   END AS IPD,
CASE WHEN MP.PT = 'A&E' THEN COUNT(MP.YN) OVER (PARTITION BY  MP.PT,mp.tti ORDER BY  mp.tti)   END AS EAC
```

The result should be in same row as they part of single select but it appear in multiple rows and do not aggregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SUM(IIF(MP.PT = 'OPD', 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY mp.tti)  AS OPD,
SUM(IIF(MP.PT = 'IPD', 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY mp.tti)  AS IPD,
SUM(IIF(MP.PT = 'A&E', 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY mp.tti)  AS EAC
```